# Service Fabric actors auto delete

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

In a ServiceFabric app, I have the necessity to create thousands of stateful Actors, so I need to avoid accumulating Actors when they become useless.

I know I can't delete an Actor from the Actor itself, but I don't want to keep track of Actors and loop to delete them.

The Actors runtime use Garbace collection to remove the deactivated Actor objects (but not their state); so, I was thinking about removing Actor state inside the OnDeactivateAsync() method and let the GC deallocate the Actor object after the usual 60min.

In theory, something like this should be **equivalent** to delete the Actor, isn't it?

```
protected override async Task OnActivateAsync()
{
    await this.StateManager.TryRemoveStateAsync("MyState");
}
```

Is there anything remaining that only explicit deletion can remove?

Comment: Does `OnDeactivateAsync` run when an actor is moved to another node? If so then this is probably not a good approach.

Comment: No, OnDeactivateAsync is only called when the Actor has been inactive in the last 60min, then the Actor is also removed from the list of active actors.
Anyway, as LoekD has pointed out, I cannot call operations that change the state in this method.

Comment: I guess you'll need to have some service that keeps track of them and deletes them then :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-lifecycle), you shouldn't change the state from OnDeactivateAsync.

If you need your Actor to not keep persisted state, you can use [attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-state-management) to change the state persistence behavior:

> **No persisted state**: State is not replicated or written to disk. This
>   level is for actors that simply don't need to maintain state reliably.

```
[StatePersistence(StatePersistence.None)]
class MyActor : Actor, IMyActor
{
}
```

Finally, you can use the [ActorService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.iactorservice.getactorsasync?view=azure-dotnet) to query Actors, see if they are inactive, and delete them.

Comment: But if in a stateless Actor I'd use StateManager to persist some data, is there any chance that a reconfiguration (my Actor moved to another node) could delete my data?

Comment: If you use 'Volatile', the data will be replicated, but not written to disk. This way movements of the ActorService replica won't affect state. If you use 'None', data will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR There are some additional resources you can free yourself (reminders) and some that only explicit deletion can remove because they are not publicly accessible.

Service Fabric Actor repo is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-services-and-actors-dotnet). I am using using persistent storage model which seems to use KvsActorStateProvider behind the scenes so I'll base the answer on that. There is a series of calls that starts at IActorService.DeleteActorAsync and continues over to [IActorManager.DeleteActorAsync](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-services-and-actors-dotnet/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors/Runtime/ActorManager.cs#L460). Lot of stuff is happening in there including a call to the state provider to remove the state part of the actor. The core code that handles this is [here](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-services-and-actors-dotnet/blob/develop/src/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors/Runtime/KvsActorStateProvider.cs#L1409) and it seems to be removing not only the state, but also reminders and some internal actor data. In addition, if you are using actor events, all event subscribers are unsubscribed for your actor.

If you really want delete-like behavior without calling the actor runtime, I guess you could register a reminder that would delete the state and unregister itself plus other reminders.

Comment: Who does call that method?
Is it the Actor itself on some sort of event?
Or from anorher Service when deleting the Actor?

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarification.
Then it really seems that [IActorService.DeleteActorAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.actors.iactorservice.deleteactorasync?view=azure-dotnet) is called by other Services, not the Actor itself during a lock (call or reminder running).

Comment: yep, I am afraid it is the case. Btw in the meantime, I've found another thread that deals with similar topic and it may have best-effort solution for you - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43873664/4998060).